# HIS-Hersteller Initiative Software - Number of Paths

Tags: embedded, qa-c

What is Number of Paths metrics? How is it different from Cyclomatic complexity?
How is it going to help improving the software quality

Comment: As any metric, it is just a value. Improvements may follow with evaluation of the value and taking measures to change the value in a desirable direction. -- Anyway, please provide more context like URLs to sources or documentation.